# Slide with javascript not working

Tags: javascript, html, slide

I tried to create a slide with 5 images but the javascript is not working

```
<body onload='slide(0)'>
    <div id='slide'>
    </div>
</body>
```

This is the javascript I used;

```
function slide(i)
{
    document.getElementById('slide')
        .style.backgroundImage = 'url(../img/' + i + '.jpg)';
    setTimeout(slide((i+1)%5), 3000);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because you are not setting  a function reference to the timer, instead just invoking the function `slide` and result is set as a callback for the timer which is undefined.

Try:

```
function slide(i) {
    document.getElementById('slide').style.backgroundImage = 'url(../img/' + i + '.jpg)';
    setTimeout(function () { //<-- Set the reference here
        slide((i + 1) % 5); //Get the mod
    }, 3000);
}
```

Or using [function.bind](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind)

```
function slide(i) {
    document.getElementById('slide').style.backgroundImage = 'url(../img/' + i + '.jpg)';
    setTimeout(slide.bind(this, (++i) % 5), 3000);//<-- Set the function context using bind with the argument as next value of i
}
```

Comment: @user2798694 Here is a demo http://jsfiddle.net/8UHGm/ Point of function reference is that you have to set a string representation for function invocation or a function reference to the setTimeout function. And you were invoking it instead of setting the reference.